# Capture browser console logs with capybara

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, capybara, console.log

I need to capture the console logs (category: info) of a browser using Ruby & Capybara. Until now I have tried using `driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)` or (`:client)` but, using this, the result is not what I want. It gives out the interaction results between selenium and browser where I can see my javascript statements sent for execution, but the resulting output fails to get captured.

Comment: What browser are you using with Selenium?

Comment: I am using chrome browser for this for now.

Comment: You can check this out if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58166640/9423417

Answer (score 32):

Whether or not logs are available when using selenium depends on what browser you are using with Selenium.  If you were using Firefox you'd be out of luck since it doesn't support the log retrieval API, however since you're using Chrome they are accessible.  The issue you're having is that, by default, only WARN or ERROR level logs are captured.  You can change this in the driver registration through the loggingPrefs capability

**Selenium 3**

```
    Capybara.register_driver :logging_selenium_chrome do |app|
      caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(loggingPrefs:{browser: 'ALL'})
      browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new()
      # browser_options.args << '--some_option' # add whatever browser args and other options you need (--headless, etc)
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options, desired_capabilities: caps)
    end
```

**Selenium 4**

```
   Capybara.register_driver :logging_selenium_chrome do |app|
     options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
     options.add_option("goog:loggingPrefs", {browser: 'ALL'})

     browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new()

     Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
     Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                 capabilities: options,
                                 browser: :chrome)
     end
   end
```

and then specify to use `:logging_selenium_chrome` as your driver

```
 Capybara.javascript_driver = :logging_selenium_chrome # or however else you're specifying which driver to use
```

which should then allow you to get the logs in your tests with

```
page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thomas Walpole. I tried to implement your solution but I am getting **uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options (NameError)** constantly. Do you have any solution so I can implement it more fastly.

Comment: @VivekKhurana what version of selenium are you using?

Comment: @VivekKhurana Update your `selenium-webdriver` gem - The `Chrome::Options` class was added in 3.4.1.  The current release is 3.5.2, upgrade to that.

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: Does not work for me at `Google Chrome 85.0.4183.83` & `ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.83`

`NoMethodError: private method 'log' called for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge:0x00007fe77c1d47``f8>`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56522499/120136  for info about `NoMethodError: private method 'log' called for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge`

Answer (score 9):

[Thomas Walpole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2709090/thomas-walpole) answer is correct but it seems that nowadays if you are using chrome as your driver you should use

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome( "goog:loggingPrefs": { browser: 'ALL' } )
```

Notice `goog:loggingPrefs` instead of `loggingPrefs` only with this solution i was able to get `console.log` printed in the log.

Took me a while and got it from here https://intellipaat.com/community/5478/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings after several frustrating attempts.

Comment: I believe this is the case for Chrome 75+, the original config works for up to Chrome 74.

Comment: Does not work for me at `Google Chrome 85.0.4183.83` & `ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.83`

`NoMethodError: private method 'log' called for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge:0x00007fe77c1d47``f8>`

Comment: for modern Chrome, you need to specify `goog:loggingPrefs` as `{browser: 'ALL'}` (see selenium configuration answers above)

Answer (score 3):

November 2022 update, use:

`page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)`

Comment: for modern Chrome, you need to specify `goog:loggingPrefs` as `{browser: 'ALL'}` (see selenium configuration answers above)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is what you want, but take a look at https://github.com/dbalatero/capybara-chromedriver-logger.

It helps me identify the [problem](https://github.com/danieldiekmeier/stimulus-controller-resolver/issues/9) with dynamic modules `import('')`. Works both locally and in Github Actions / Circle CI by displaying failed loads of assets (which i believe outputs as `console.error`).

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answers from @thomas-walpole and @0ds0, rummaging through various other posts, and following-up on deprecation warnings led me to this code (working as of July 2023 w/ Chrome `v114`). It also reproduces the code that Capybara uses to [build the original](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/registrations/drivers.rb) `selenium_chrome` driver.

```js
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  browser_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
    # Workaround https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2650&q=load&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary
    opts.add_argument('--disable-site-isolation-trials')

    opts.add_option('goog:loggingPrefs', browser: 'ALL')
  end

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

---

I store the logs like so:

```ruby
config.prepend_after(js: true) do |example|
  Selenium::WebDriver.logger.info "Finishing Capybara test: #{example.location}\n"

  browser_logs = page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)
  log_str = SystemConfigurationHelpers.make_browser_log_string(browser_logs)

  Selenium::WebDriver.logger.info "** Browser logs for #{example.location}:\n\n#{log_str}\n"

  driver_logs = page.driver.browser.logs.get(:driver)
  log_str = SystemConfigurationHelpers.make_browser_log_string(driver_logs)

  Selenium::WebDriver.logger.info "** Driver logs for #{example.location}:\n\n#{log_str}\n"
end
```

the code that makes the log entries look nice is:

```ruby
module SystemConfigurationHelpers
  # Convenience method used for displaying browser log statements extracted from Selenium
  # @param [Array<String>] collection of browser log statements
  # @return [String] newline-delimited list of formatted log messages
  def self.make_browser_log_string(logs)
    logs.inject(+'') do |result, log|
      result << "* #{log.time} #{log.level}: #{log.message}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

---

Another way to save logs to a file `log/browser.log` after each test in `minitest`:

```rb
# test/application_system_test_case.rb

def self.browser_logger
  @browser_logger ||= Logger.new(
    Rails.root.join("log", "browser.log"),
    formatter: proc { |_, _, _, msg| msg }
  )
end

def self.logger_formatter
  @logger_formatter ||= Logger::Formatter.new
end

def browser_logger
  self.class.browser_logger
end

def logger_formatter
  self.class.logger_formatter
end

def before_teardown
  browser_logs = page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)

  browser_logs.each do |log|
    browser_logger.unknown do
      # Keep microseconds and local machine timezone
      seconds, microseconds = log.timestamp.divmod(1000)
      time = Time.at(seconds, microseconds * 1000)

      # Write log message with test name
      logger_formatter.call(log.level, time, name, log.message)
    end
  end

  super
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the deprecated warning about `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities`.

This is working for me, and seems inline with what the documentation suggests:

```
    ...
    # this gives us access to the javascript logs using `page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)` in our test
    # see https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/
    service = Selenium::WebDriver::Service.chrome
    service.args << '--log-level=ALL'

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :chrome,
      options: options,
      service: service
    )
```