# How to display JS errors in Capybara + ChromeDriver?

Tags: javascript, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I have an integration test setup that uses RSpec + Capybara. We recently switched from PhantomJS to headless Chromedriver and I miss that javascript errors are not displayed anymore.

Is there a convenient way of configuring Chromedriver so that javascript errors show up in the log output of capybara tests?

The ways of accessing the javascript errors I found (see below) all are a bit cumbersome or not really what I was looking for.

- setting an explicit log output path as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925681/1870317)
- accessing the (kind of cut back) error log through the driver interface as described in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gkop/1371962)

Answer (score 10):

With

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(type: :feature) do
    STDERR.puts page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
  end
end
```

one can print out the logs after each example, that is a feature spec with RSpec. Should be similar in other test frameworks. This does not fail the example however.

Comment: This is exactly what is mentioned in the comments of the gist linked to in the question.

Comment: This is now `page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your second method is referring to the comments in that gist rather than the method that requires installing an extension, then no there isn't.  Selenium is basing its functionality/feature support off the WebDriver spec - https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html - which doesn't specify anything about reporting JS errors back to the automation client.

Note - there are configuration options for the Chrome logs which may change the verbosity and get rid of the "kind of cut back" issue - see [Capture browser console logs with capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278514/capture-browser-console-logs-with-capybara)