# Chromedriver `driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)` fails on chromedriver 75.0.3770.8

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

While accessing `driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)` on chromedriver 75.0.3770.8 I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `log' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge:0x0000562dc661c250> (NoMethodError)
```

Works fine on 74.0.3729.6

from: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7270

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capybara 3.24 now works around this issue when used with chromedriver >= 75.0.3770.90

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately, Capybara 3.16+ does not work with Ruby 2.3.

Comment: @codener yeah Ruby 2.3 went end of life - time to upgrade

Comment: @Cristik I disagree with that - everyone is able to upgrade but some people determine the time/money aren't worth it to them.  If you're still running production code with Ruby 2.3 you've made the determination that your legal liability around security issues is outweighed by the costs to upgrade and that's your right, but if you've made that decision why would you still be wanting to run tests with modern test tool versions - it's not like you're going to actually spend the time/money to fix anything they find.

Answer (score 11):

in recent `selenium-webdriver` (4.4.0) with recent Chrome (105), `manage.logs` is gone but this works:

```
page.driver.browser.logs.get(:browser)
```

Answer (score 8):

Chrome 75 defaults to W3C mode, which doesn't specify a way to get log access.

The short term fix for this issue is to disable `w3c` via `chromeOptions`.

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless window-size=1280,800], w3c: false },
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
                                 browser: :chrome,
                                 desired_capabilities: capabilities
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As specified in the [release notes](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for Chrome Driver 75, capability `loggingPrefs` has been renamed to `goog:loggingPrefs`, as required by W3C standard. Thus, the code setting the capabilities should be adjusted and there will be no necessity of falling back to non-w3c mode at least due to the log capturing reason.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? The method `log` doesn't exist on the W3C bridge so just changing the name of the pref isn't really going to fix the OPs issue.

Comment: Yes, this fixed my issue (in Java)

Comment: Oh - you're using Java -- Each of the selenium language bindings is different. Your suggestion will make no difference on the ruby bindings this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

As a short term fix, it seems you can monkey-patch the functionality back in (tested using Selenium-WebDriver v3.142.3):

You will need to add/patch the method to the Chrome::Bridge:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    module Chrome
      module Bridge
        COMMANDS = remove_const(:COMMANDS).dup
        COMMANDS[:get_log] = [:post, 'session/:session_id/log']
        COMMANDS.freeze

        def log(type)
          data = execute :get_log, {}, {type: type.to_s}

          Array(data).map do |l|
            begin
              LogEntry.new l.fetch('level', 'UNKNOWN'), l.fetch('timestamp'), l.fetch('message')
            rescue KeyError
              next
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your capabilities, you will need to switch to using "goog:loggingPrefs" instead of just "loggingPrefs":

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome('goog:loggingPrefs' => {browser: 'ALL'})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, desired_capabilities: caps)

driver.execute_script('console.log("test");')

puts driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)
#=> INFO 2019-06-13 21:48:03 -0400: console-api 362:34 "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that just upgrading the `selenium-webdriver` gem to 3.142.4+ fixes the issue even if you are using an outdated Capybara.

`driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)` works just as before.

From the changelog:

```
3.142.4 (2019-09-02)
====================

Chrome:
  * Added support for new command for getting logs in ChromeDriver 76+
    with W3C mode on
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome,   desired_capabilities: {
      "chromeOptions" => {
        w3c: false
      },
      'goog:loggingPrefs' => {browser: 'ALL'}
    })  
end
```

and in the log place

```
puts ""
puts "*** Browser logs:"
puts ""

puts page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get("browser").map { |log_entry|
  "[#{Time.at(log_entry.timestamp.to_i)}] [#{log_entry.level}] #{log_entry.message}"
}.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me none of suggested solution worked. What helped was

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.logging_prefs = {browser: 'ALL'}
```

The options internally stores `logging_prefs` from the initialization in the instance variable, and when processing options it sets up browser-dependent config. Although when doing so in `new(logging_prefs: {browser: 'ALL'})` it complains about w3c incompatible params. But hopefully the options do have the accessor for this.